# Debug a local maven dependency with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependency-management

i have two maven projects, the first one is a library and the other one use it to works properly, the both have to elvolve regardless each other, this is why i use two different project.

But breakpoints on my library code doesn't work when i launch my app (the second application).

This is how i include my library in the second project's POM (my IDE is eclipse and projects are in the same workspaces)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mcamier</groupId>
        <artifactId>lazyEngine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/../lazyEngine/target/lazyEngine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quick fix to this is to right-click on your application project in Eclipse and choose Properties, remove the library jar from the external jars, and add the library Eclipse project to projects (i.e. the list of project dependencies).